# Converter a string "5.541,00" para int em C#

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

Qual a maneira correta de converter uma string com o texto "5.541,88" para `int`?

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
int valor = int.Parse("5.541,88");
```

Mas não consigo, pois retorna o erro:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Utilize Convert.ToInt32()

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 7):

A forma correta é usando o estilo de valor e a cultura que está para ele conseguir identificar o padrão.

E claro, verificar se deu certo antes de usar, porque pode falhar ([`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)), não vou deixar a aplicação quebrar, nem usar uma exceção para uma situação não excepcional, parece ser esperado que o dado venha com falhas. Se é garantido que o dado não virá com falhas de formatação, aí poderá usar o `Parse()` e sem exceção.

Vou usar `decimal` porque claramente isso é um valor monetário, não faz muito sentido tentar pegar o valor inteiro dele, mas se quiser pode fazê-lo em seguida, só tenha certeza que quer perder parte do valor, isso não faz parte da conversão em si.

Se quiser mesmo converter para inteiro pode fazer uma conversão explícita (é melhor que um *cast* porque deixa claro a semântica desejada e é o mais provável para pegar a melhor aproximação - [`ToInt32()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Decimal_)).

Mas se deseja realmente descartar os centavos, então trunque o valor ([`Truncate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

Mas se é valor monetário e deseja só ter a parte inteira então deveria manter o tipo usando o [`Truncate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.truncate?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do tipo `decimal`.

Fiz todas opções em:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;
using static System.Math;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        if (!decimal.TryParse("5.541,88", NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"), out var valor)) WriteLine("Formato inválido para conversão");
        WriteLine($"Decimal: {valor}");
        WriteLine($"Inteiro: {ToInt32(valor)}");
        WriteLine($"Inteiro truncado: {Truncate(valor)}");
        WriteLine($"Decimal truncado: {decimal.Truncate(valor)}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uGp8xs). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tpa2iA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/Decimal.cs).

Comment: Quem negativou poderia falar o que tem errado na resposta. Se tem erro é importante para a comunidade que seja demonstrando para as pessoas não aprenderem errado. Eu não consigo ver um erro sequer, perguntei para outras pessoas que entendem e não viram também, então parece só voto de um grupo inconformado com alguma coisa.

Comment: Verifiquei, acho que não tinha adicionado o `using static System.Console;` no momento que fui executar o seu código. Agora está 100% depois que adicionei funcionou.

Answer (score -4):

A conversão não está a funcionar porque ele não deteta o formato do valor, tente assim:

```
  string ii = "5541.88";
        float value = float.Parse(ii, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Comment: Você sabe que isto não resulta no que ele quer, tem problema conceitual e quebra a aplicação se o dado estiver vindo de fonte não confiável?

Comment: Sua string `ii` não é igual ao que o cara postou, se fosse assim seria uma conversão bem mais direta.

Comment: Eu simplesmente respondi a pergunta "Converter a String “5.541,00” para Int em C#" com um simples ajuste que a variável não pode inteira(possível erro na pergunta), qual o meu erro aqui? o objetivo não é ter a variavel valor com o valor "5541.88"???

Comment: Não tem erro na pergunta, inclusive as duas respostas dadas tratam este caso.